# How often can one do a calisthenics workout?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, calisthenics

I was just exposed to [Calisthenics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calisthenics) and I loved what these people could do on the pull up bar. I researched and found out a few routines for the beginners and would like to start up with them. However there was no mention of how frequently these routines should be done.

I am no beginner to the Gym. Have been around for a long time. I have been doing SS routine for more then a year consistently and doing a lot of schedules and stuff for years before that. I am 6ft 1 Inches and weight 210 pounds and am happy with my size and strength. I have no plans to grow any bigger. My current lifts are close to 200 pounds and I am happy with that too, don't want to get any stronger either. My basic idea is I love working out so I think Calisthenic will add good variety.

I read some where that these workouts can be done 6 days a week. Please let me know what would be a good frequency ?? also what is a good place to learn more about the same.

The routine for a beginner looks like below:

- Pull-ups
- Inverted rows
- Dips
- Push-ups
- Squats

Do 3 sets per each exercise and 5 sets of squats, doing as many repetitions as you can.

thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what the workouts/routines actually involve? Difficult to say how often you should be doing them if we don't know what you're going to be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geek,

A couple quick thoughts about this routine: One is that this is not a beginner routine (most beginners won't be able to perform pull-ups or dips), and two is that doing max out reps for each exercise is not the best way to start out of any exercise, workout or routine.  You are at a higher risk for injuries (most commonly is tendonitis and extreme muscle soreness that may last for days).

I have been working with high level gymnasts and college athletes over 10 years now, and one of my specialty is to design and implement calisthenic workout routines for all athletes at all fitness levels.

To answer your question specifically, I have broken down your workout routine including the frequency and duration for you.  I do think that since you have been doing SS for over a year consistently, you should consider yourself as an intermediate level, not a beginner in my opinion.  So here it is:

Your workout for the first 2 weeks:

1. Chin-ups
2. Push-ups
3. Inverted Rows
4. Dips
5. Squats

Workout 3 days per week with one day of rest in between.  Try 3 sets of 10-15 reps.  Rest 45-60 seconds between sets and between exercises.

Next 2 weeks

1. Chin-ups
2. Gator Push-ups
3. Inverted Rows
4. Dips
5. Squat Jumps

Workout 3 days per week with one day of rest in between.  Try 4 sets of 10-20 reps.  Rest 45-60 seconds between sets and between exercises

Next 4 weeks

1. Pull-ups
2. Plyo Push-ups
3. Inverted Rows
4. Dips
5. Tuck Jumps

Workout 3 days per week with one day of rest in between.  Try 4 sets of 10-20 reps.  Rest 45-60 seconds between sets and between exercises

The maintenance phase: You can do the same exercises as above (pull-ups, plyo push-ups, inverted rows, dips and tuck jumps), trying for 4-5 sets of max effort, resting 30 seconds between sets and between exercises.  The key is that you will only need to do this workout 3 days per week, not 6 days per week.

I hope this is helpful.  Give it a try and let us know!

Good luck!